# Can I use the integral test for this serie? $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}ne^{-n^{2}}$

Tags: sequences-and-series

Can I use the integral test for this serie? $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}ne^{-n^{2}}$

It satisfies all three of the integral test criteria

Comment: Yes: by the integral test this series is convergent.

Comment: is it important what "k" is when integrating? $\int_{k}^{\infty}xe^{-x^2}$?

Comment: You can use the integral test, but the ratio test will be less work: $(n+1)/n$ goes to $1$ and $e^{-(n+1)^2}/e^{-n^2} = e^{-2n-1}$ goes to $0$. Done.

Comment: No, the k doesn't affect convergence or divergence, because the difference between $\int_1^\infty f(x)\,dx$ and $\int_k^\infty f(x)\,dx$ is $\int_1^k f(x)\,dx$ which is finite, as long as this isn't the other kind of improper integral. It will however affect the value if the integrals are convergent.

Answer (score 1):

You can compare $\sum_{n=M}^\infty n\exp(-n^2)$ to $\int_M^\infty x\exp(-x^2)dx$ for sufficiently large $M$. Show the convergence of $\int_M^\infty x\exp(-x^2)dx$ by upper-bounding it with $\int_M^\infty x\exp(-x)dx$.

Comment: You could show the "upper bound" by actually integrating the function. $\int xe^{-x^2}dx = \frac{-e^{-x^2}}{2}$

Comment: That's right. I was recently dealing with hard integrals, so I missed this one :)